# Regarding html button being totally invisible

Tags: html, jsp

I am not able to totally remove the button, even if I typed `input style="visibility:hidden"`, I am still seeing the button.

Can anyone suggest the solution? I would like to change it in my jsp file.

Comment: you can post your code and css? It could be that you have a typo, conflicting css, etc. As well as `visibility:hidden` in CSS there is `display:none` which does not affect the layout but does hide the object.

Comment: visibility: hidden hide the field or component but still it takes own space or area in layout or page but display: none hide the field or component but doesn't take any space or area in layout or page.